# cURL error in various homebrew installations

Tags: curl, openssl, homebrew, secure-transport

I'm using my (quite old) Macbook with macOS 10.10. I have been struggling to install the following programs using homebrew: ffmpeg, cairo, and sox. Whenever I run `brew install ffmpeg` it al runs well until eventually, I run into the following error:

```
==> Downloading https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.64/glib-2.64.3.tar.xz

curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
Error: Failed to download resource "glib"
Download failed: https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.64/glib-2.64.3.tar.xz
```

As far as I know, there is an issue with the version of cURL being used, which does not support OpenSSL, and SecureTransport is getting in the way. I saw this when running:

```
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

It seems that the cURL that is being used is the one built in with the OS, I tried switching to the homebrew one by editing my `$PATH` in my `.bash_profile`, and ran the following, finding SecureTransport again:

```
$ which curl
/usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
$ curl -V
curl 7.71.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0) libcurl/7.71.1 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Release-Date: 2020-07-01
```

but this was no help. I also tried `brew upgrade`,`brew uninstall curl` and then `brew install curl-openssl` but this homebrew installation also runs into the same curl(35) error.

How can I disable SecureTransport?
Is there any other possible fix?
Is it necessary for me to update my macOS to a more recent version?

Answer (score 1):

Use the homebrew-installed `curl` instead. For that set `HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL`. From [`man brew`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage)

> If set, always use a Homebrew-installed curl(1) rather than the system version. Automatically set if the system version of curl is too old.

Answer (score 1):

Run a command:

```
export HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1
```

It will set an environment variable for the current shell session to use brew curl which is newer than is installed on your system.

You can read about it on official [homebrew documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage).

Comment: Preceding the command with HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1 will also do the trick

Answer (score 0):

First of all, feel pretty bad for your situation that homebrew only supports the latest three MacOS versions (which are high-sierra, mojave and catalina at this moment), this aligns with the Apple's security patch policy as well.

Second, regarding your `glib` downloading issue, I just did a download myself, seems working fine now (we usually use `bintray` homebrew mirror to mitigate the issue like this), but I just checked the homebrew core codebase, we did not have mirror for gnome source artifacts though (hope that you won't run into such issue again) .

Third, regarding how to override the MacOS default curl, you can just do `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`.

Here is what I have in my local before/after:

```
$ ls -al $(which curl)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  185072 May 20 04:14 /usr/bin/curl

$ curl --version
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.6.5 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.1
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

```
$ ls -al $(which curl)
-r-xr-xr-x  1 rchen  staff  209876 Jul  4 15:58 /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl

$ curl --version
curl 7.71.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0) libcurl/7.71.1 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.11
Release-Date: 2020-07-01
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL UnixSockets
```

Final comment is if you don't have to install the latest `ffmpeg`, `cairo`, and `sox`, I can probably find you the bottles for `MacOS 10.10`.

Hope it helps.